# Login Via Linkedin in Symfony 4.2

Tags: php, symfony4

I am working on a form where I need to get LinkedIn profile data in the fields.

the form is on multiple URLs as I have a careers page where multiple jobs available on each job page there is a form and my URL becomes like: `https://www.xxxxx.com/careers/job1` `https://www.xxxxx.com/careers/job2` `https://www.xxxxx.com/careers/job3` and I have the main form on `https://www.xxxxx.com/careers/` this URL as well. I tried some javascript plugin but found not working and found it's not being supported now as specified here [developer linkedin](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk) then I tried a PHP script to do that and did the following.

login via LinkedIn button:
`<a href="{{ linkedinUrl?linkedinUrl:'javascript:;' }}" class="btn linkedin"><span>Use your LinkedIn profile</span></a></p>`

Below is my controller where I am fetching and setting Linkedin data in session to show in the form: I called a callback function here to get Linkedin data from API.

```
    public function careers( Request $request ) {
    $CustomerToken = new JobApplication();
    $session       = new Session();

    $form = $this->createForm( JobApplicationType::class, $CustomerToken );
    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['code'] ) ) {
        $user    = $this->linkedinCallback();
        $session = new Session();
        $session->set( 'linkedinUserFirstName', $user->firstName );
        $session->set( 'linkedinUserLastName', $user->lastName );
        $session->set( 'linkedinUserEmail', $user->emailAddress );
    }
    $linkedinUserFirstName = '';
    if ( ! empty( $session->get( 'linkedinUserFirstName' ) ) ) {
        $linkedinUserFirstName = $session->get( 'linkedinUserFirstName' );
    }
    $linkedinUserLastName = '';
    if ( ! empty( $session->get( 'linkedinUserLastName' ) ) ) {
        $linkedinUserLastName = $session->get( 'linkedinUserLastName' );
    }
    $linkedinUserEmail = '';
    if ( ! empty( $session->get( 'linkedinUserEmail' ) ) ) {
        $linkedinUserEmail = $session->get( 'linkedinUserEmail' );
    }
    session_destroy();
    $linkedin['client_id']     = "<client_id>";
    $linkedin['client_secret'] = "<client_secret>";
    $linkedin['redirect_uri']  = "<redirect_uri>";
    $linkedin['csrf_token']    = random_int( 1111111, 9999999 );
    $linkedin['scopes']        = "r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress";

    return $this->render( 'pages/careers.html.twig', [
        'controller_name'       => 'PagesController',
        'jobApplicationForm'    => $form->createView(),
        'linkedinUrl'           => 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=' . $linkedin['client_id'] . '&redirect_uri=' . $linkedin['redirect_uri'] . '&state=' . $linkedin['csrf_token'] . '&scope=' . $linkedin['scopes'] . '',
        'linkedinUserFirstName' => $linkedinUserFirstName,
        'linkedinUserLastName'  => $linkedinUserLastName,
        'linkedinUserEmail'  => $linkedinUserEmail,
    ] );
}
```

My callback function where I am getting linkedin profile data.

```
    public function linkedinCallback() {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['code'] ) ) {
        $linkedin['client_id']     = "<client_id>";
        $linkedin['client_secret'] = "<client_secret>";
        $linkedin['redirect_uri']  = "<redirect_uri>";
        $code        = $_REQUEST['code'];
        $url         = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";
        $params      = [
            'client_id'     => $linkedin['client_id'],
            'client_secret' => $linkedin['client_secret'],
            'redirect_uri'  => $linkedin['redirect_uri'],
            'code'          => $code,
            'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
        ];
        $accessToken = $this->curl( $url, http_build_query( $params ) );
        $accessToken = json_decode( $accessToken )->access_token;

        $url  = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,pictureUrls::(original),headline,publicProfileUrl,location,industry,positions,email-address)?format=json&oauth2_access_token=" . $accessToken;
        $user = file_get_contents( $url, false );

        return ( json_decode( $user ) );

    }
}
```

I tried hwioauthbundle as well but couldn't find it working for me.

I have 2 problems: 
First: I need linkedin popup for login.
second: when I click on linkedin button it takes me to the linkedin authentication URL to login my account and redirects me to the url I specified in my linkedin app and in my code as well with query string of `code` and `state` but when I refresh the page is goes to 500 and says `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$access_token`. also this URL wouldn't work on the specific job link which will be dyanamic like for job 1, job 2 etc. I tried many solutions, but couldn't get success yet.

My symfony version is 4.2